# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" compile error

Tags: sql, oracle, pls-00103

Can't find anything wrong with this, but it compiles with errors. Anyone see what I am blind to?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myusername.fun_hr_format_phone (tmp in VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 
 IS tmpVar VARCHAR2(12);

BEGIN

  SELECT DECODE(
    LENGTH(tmp),
    10, SUBSTR(tmp,1,3) || '-' || SUBSTR(tmp,4,3) || '-' || SUBSTR(tmp,7,4),
    7, SUBSTR(tmp,1,3) || '-' || SUBSTR(tmp,4,4), tmp
  ) INTO tmpVar FROM dual;

  RETURN tmpVar;

  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN NULL;
    WHEN OTHERS THEN RAISE;

END;
/
```

Comment: @user2599766: Code looks perfect ,which tool you are using?[SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d1b14)

Comment: Type `show errors` to display the syntax errors and edit your post to include the error(s).  Your `when others then raise` clause is pointless and should be removed but that isn't causing a compilation error.

Comment: Working in TOAD, the error is:

PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   begin function package pragma procedure subtype type use
   <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> form
   current cursor

Comment: Odd thing is that this compiles for 2 others, its just my toad instance that is causing problems... I'm using TOAD version 12.0.0.61

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using SQL*Plus: beware of empty lines, your code it totally correct syntactically.

Comment: SQL*Plus doesn't mind them for PL/SQL anyway. And there's a `set sqlblanklines` command to toggle whether it minds them for SQL.